# How to access set of objects that are saved in another set of objects

Tags: java, list, set

I have set of e.g objects Person who have inside of them have set of objects Abilities, and how can i check if two persons have same Abilities, in another words how can I access another set in one set, only results i found that i need to use for each loop but can i use for each for two sets that are one in another
Code using arrays looks like this

```
Abilities[] a1 = {new Abilities("sing"), new Abilities("dance"), new Abilities("shoot")};
Abilities[] a2 = {new Abilities("fly"), new Abilities("run"), new Abilities("box")};
Abilities[] a3 = {new Abilities("dig"), new Abilities("build"), new Abilities("mine")};
Person p1 = new Person(a3);
Person[] persons = {new Person(a1), new Person(a2), new Person(a3)};
Abilities[] a4 = p1.getAbilities();

for(int i = 0; i < persons.lenght; i++) 
      {
           Person[] tmp = persons[i].getAbilities();
           if (Arrays.equals(a4, tmp))
               throw new SameAbilitiesException("Persons with same abilities exception!");
        }
```

How to refactor it using sets for both Abilities and Persons

Comment: You spelled `length` wrong is `Person.length`. Is that what is causing the error or is it just a typo?

Comment: no i wrote this just for example here in stack overflow directly without compiling but i will edit ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//This code show you how to make set of obecjts , so just do this for a3,a4 as well.
Set<Abilities> a1 = new HashSet<Abilities>();

a1.add(new Abilities("sing"));
a1.add(new Abilities("dance"));
a1.add(new Abilities("shoot"));

  Set<Abilities> a2 = new HashSet<Abilities>();


 a2.add(new Abilities("sing"));
 a2.add(new Abilities("dance"));
 a2.add(new Abilities("shoot"));


//You should remember to change from array of abilities to set in the definition of your Person class.
Person p1 = new Person(a1);
Person p2 = new Person(a2);
```

---

```
Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
persons.add(p1);
persons.add(p2);
```

we will use iterator with set here.

```
       Person temp = null; 
Iterator<Person> iterator =  persons.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext(){
  Person tempPerson = iterator.next();
for(Person p : persons){ //This for loop will compare with all other objects
   if(p!=tempPerson){
  if(compareSets(tempPerson.getAbilities(),p.getAbilities())){
  throw new SameAbilitiesException("Persons with same abilities");
     }
   }  
  }
}
```

The Method which you can use to check if two sets are the same.

```
//check whether set2 contains all elements of set1
private static boolean compareSets(Set<Abilities> set1, Set<Abilities> set2) {
    if(set1.isEmpty() || set2.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }       
    return set2.containsAll(set1);
}
```

**if you want to keep your code with Array :**

```
 Person temp = null; 
    
    for(int i = 0; i < Person.length; i++) 
          {
    // Here it will be array of type Abilites not Person
              Abilities[] tmp = persons[i].getAbilities();
//This for loop will start from first index to compare
             for(int j=0; j<Person.length;j++){
if(i!=j){ // This if because we don't want to compare same array with it's self 

       if (Arrays.equals(Person[i].getAbilities(), tmp))
                   throw new SameAbilitiesException("Persons with same abilities exception!");
}
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few improvements could make:

1. Use `List<Abilities>` instead of `Abilities[]`. This will allow dynamic expansion of abilities at runtime.
2. Now you changed arrays to `List<Abilities>`, your `Person` class method should also needs to return `List<Abilities>` when you call `persons[i].getAbilities();`.
3. You can use `List#containsAll()` method to verify that all the abilities are present for a given person inside your for-loop.

`if (mandatorySkillsList.containsAll(personAbilitiesList))`